# C# print long int with string

Tags: c#, string, long-integer

I can call it properly in the first part of the code this is built into a long list of if else statements.

```
if (Ten < 0) {
        Ten = x;
    long y = System.Int64.Parse (One + "" + Two + ""//... code continues);
        print ("Press Tab to confirm to play with " + y + ".");
            ChosenNum ();
    } else if (Ten > -1) {
        print ("Press Tab to confirm to play with " + y + ".");
    }
```

In the code just after and in the function below it doesn't call the long y.

```
void ChosenNum ()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.Tab)) {
        print ("You have chosen " + y);
        StartGame2 ();
    }
}
```

I want to call the long y in the code just after and in the function, if I assign long y; at the start of my class It conflicts with my int y; Creating a long w for instance will cause the need for extra code, but would like to find a solution without doing so.

Comment: I can't understand a word from your question..

Comment: Please don't use variable names like `y` and `w`. It makes code **very** hard to understand.

Comment: Put it simplely I can call the long y where it is declared, but it will not translate to other parts of my code. The long y = the 10 digit number.

Comment: long y = System.Int64.Parse (One + "" + Two + ""//... code continues);
        print ("Press Tab to confirm to play with " + y + "."); 
it works here. But no where else.

Comment: @Merdinarchfire I still can't understand nothing. I don't know what you wanted to try, in which scope you tried to get access to your "long y", but you should learn about scope, calling functions (maybe you need to send "Y" as param to "'chosenNum _(long y)_'.. try to think about your code as if you DON'T know it and you'll understand we're missing information

Comment: thats because you are just creating that variable within the condition please create the variable at form level and assign the value rather creating otherwise you can pass y as a parameter to choseNum(long y)

Comment: Yes, thank you. I needed to create the long at the beginning of my code, using long w instead. Then created additional code to make use of the long w in the same context I was using the long y. Sorry if I don't make much sense. But it has be solved you guys helped my look in the right direction to figure it out. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you simply do this :

```
void ChosenNum (long value)
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.Tab)) {
        print ("You have chosen " + value);
        StartGame2 ();
    }
}
```

Then call it :

```
if (Ten < 0) {
    Ten = x;
long y = System.Int64.Parse (One + "" + Two + ""//... code continues);
    print ("Press Tab to confirm to play with " + y + ".");
        ChosenNum (y);//pass it here, this is my change
} else if (Ten > -1) {
    print ("Press Tab to confirm to play with " + y + ".");
}
```